# Scrape content inside DIV - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I am scraping with `Python` using `BeautifulSoap`

I have to scrape the text inside `DIV`

```
<div class="map-address">
   O'Riordan Street,               
   Mascot 2020 NSW Australia, 
   (Corner Robey Street)
</div>
```

I have this code

```
print (soup.select('div.map-address'))
```

But I get this output

```
[<div class="map-address">
   O'Riordan Street,               
   Mascot 2020 NSW Australia, 
   (Corner Robey Street)
</div>]
```

I have also tried

```
print (soup.select('div.map-address').text)
# Error ... no attribute named text
```

Comment: Downvotes are accepted but with some explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it:

```
if not soup.select('div.map-address'):
    print ("No Address")
else:
    print (hotel_page_soup.select('div.map-address')[0].text)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
print (soup.select('div.map-address')[0].get_text().strip())
```

Remember that `select` is returning you a list. That's why you see the [] around it when you print it and also why you get an error when you try to read the `text` property (you're asking for the `text` property of the list).

So if you take the zeroth element and call `get_text` on it it will get you what you want. I added `strip` to remove surrounding whitespace.

Not pretty but it works.

Comment: thanks for `strip()`
M a PHP dev but coding first time in Python

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use this,

```
>>> for i in soup.select('div.map-address'):
    print(i.string)



   O'Riordan Street,               
   Mascot 2020 NSW Australia, 
   (Corner Robey Street)
```

Through [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and list comprehension.

```
>>> print ([i.text for i in soup.select('div.map-address')][0])
```

Through `soup.find`. I this we explicitly tell what would be the value of class attribute is.

```
>>> print([i.string for i in soup.find('div', class_='map-address')][0])

   O'Riordan Street,               
   Mascot 2020 NSW Australia, 
   (Corner Robey Street)
```

Comment: I have only one DIV so why should I use FOR loop

Comment: The loop nicely handles if there are 0 or more than 1 `divs`. There may not be now but you never know in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Is this beautiful soup library or scrapy?

The syntax is looking quite different from beautiful soup...

I would rather suggest

```py
print(soup.find("div", {"class": "map-address"})[0].text)
```